# Can high tempretures damage my laptop CPU or fan?

Tags: cpu, overheating

I just had my laptop serviced. Before it was 80 degrees Celsius when i watched YouTube videos and up to 100 degrees Celsius.

In the store they cleaned my CPU fan and it's now maximum 50 degrees Celsius. Can the old high temperature have damaged my laptop CPU or the fan?

Comment: Are you sure about the 80 or even 100 degC? Could it be Fahrenheit instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think the high heat damaged your laptop?

If the temperature gets ***too*** high, it's supposed to automatically shut itself down, and probably first do things like limit the CPU frequency/speed/workload to lower the temperature.

If the laptop still works now, then it's probably not damaged.

If you think high heat could shorten the lifespan of your laptop... that's a debatable possibility. I think it *could* have, but there's no reliable way to find out, short of buying 100 identical laptops and doing heat & lifetime experiments on them (maybe similar to how the manufacturers estimate their warranty periods). It's guaranteed that it should keep working at least until the warranty runs out...

Comment: Can heat damage your electronics?  Heat can damage pretty much anything.  The question is how long is it exposed to those temperatures.  A CPU reaching its thermal limits and shutting off won't damage it.  A CPU reaching its thermal limits, it not shutting off, will damage it.  You also need more than 100 identical laptops to determine anything, if you had maybe 10,000, you might be able to calculate a reliable MTTF number.